# How do I save number of columns in Terminal with C++ to a variable?

Tags: c++, terminal, ncurses

I've been searching quite a lot, and all I've had are answers for C, not C++.  I'm using Linux, so I won't be able to use windows.h

What I need to do is get the number of columns in the terminal window it's running, then print something in the middle with ncurses.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: the C answers work in C++ as well. In any case you're going to use some API call which will most likely be C

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan is right; anything that's C will also work in C++.  C++ specific answers are good if there are API or more OO ways of doing it, but don't be afraid to go the C route when your solution lies there.  If you really want something OO, you can create an OO wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be using ncurses, just [use the facility](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/printw.html) (section 6.3.4) that exists in the library to do it:

```
int main(void) {
    int rows, cols;

    initscr();
    getmaxyx(stdscr, rows, cols); // you now have the max for both axis
}
```

It's important to note that you should be refreshing these values (and the screen) upon receiving a SIGWINCH signal, or your windows will look rather odd if someone changes the height or width of their terminal program.

There is no C++ version of ncurses because it's not needed, but many prefer to create their own wrapper *around* it to get easier access to the functionality they want in the context of their application. The `ncurses.h` header will check to see if C++ is being used, and adjust accordingly:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
```

To use it, simply link it and use it procedurally, or use it in whatever class you have dealing with terminal I/O in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how :

```
int columns=system("tput cols");
```

You need to `#include<stdlib.h>`.
Then you can use `mvprintw(y, x, "your text here") ;` to print text [wherever](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/wprintw.html) you want.

Note `tput lines` gives the number of rows, in case you want it too.

Note that i am ignoring the line `I've been searching quite a lot, and all I've had are answers for C, not C++.`. This is (one way of) how you do it, *C or C++*.
You may refer to [this](https://github.com/madaan/gamex/blob/master/BitOps.cpp) as an example.